# Making script continue when a command fails

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax

I am writing a script to remove unwanted files in my $HOME.

I need the script to continue if a command within the for-loop returns an error.
I tried to follow the advice from another Stack Overflow thread which said to use this format:

`command || true`

However, this does not seem to work for my scenario where I am executing code within a for-loop. The script exits the loop, and continues executing the lines after the loop.

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=(
  "Desktop"
  ".yarnrc"
)

cd $HOME
for file in $files;
do
  echo "current file: $file"
  rm -r "$file" || :
done

echo "hello world"
```

Output:

```
current file: Desktop
rm: cannot remove 'Desktop': No such file or directory
hello world
```

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$file` expands *only* to `Desktop`, not all elements of the array. `$file` is equivalent to `${file[0]}`.

```
cd
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  echo "current file: $file"
  rm -r -- "$file"
done
```

You aren't using `set -e`, so whether `rm` succeeds or fails as no effect on the rest of the loop or script.

Comment: I think @LUD migh as well use `rm -r -- "${files[@]}"`.

Comment: Probably. I left the loop to preserve the logging, and (though not relevant in this case) the `for` loop isn't limited to how many array items can be iterated over, while there might be an OS-induced limit on how many arguments can be passed to `rm` at one time.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why the ```{ }``` are needed? I tried to run the script without them, but that didn't work. I know the curly braces can be used to expand parts words. Like ```${foo}bar```. But I don't understand what they are doing in this scenario.

Comment: `${...}` is the canonical syntax for parameter expansion; they can optionally be *dropped* in the common case when only the parameter name is given. For expansions involving array indexing and other operators (e.g., `${foo:-3}`), the braces cannot be dropped.

Comment: `"$file[@]"` would expand to `Desktop[@]`, not each element of the array as a separate word.